# How to use translator for two languages in beamer

Tags: beamer, languages, translator

Using `translator` package in beamer presentation to translate string like `theorem` to a single language is simple and clear, how about two languages ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish,french]{babel}

\uselanguage{french}
\languagepath{french}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\today
\begin{theorem}
I will translate \structure{\translate[to=french]{theorem}} but not theorem
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\selectlanguage{spanish}

%\uselanguage{spanish}
%\languagepath{spanish}

\begin{frame}
\today
\begin{theorem}
I will translate \structure{\translate[to=spanish]{theorem}} but not theorem
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load languages in `\documentclass`, just before `babel` and in the same order, so the last language, i.e. French is the default.

```
\documentclass[spanish,french]{beamer}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\today
\begin{theorem}
I will translate \structure{\translate[to=french]{theorem}} but not theorem
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\selectlanguage{spanish}

\begin{frame}
\today
\begin{theorem}
I will translate \structure{\translate[to=spanish]{theorem}} but not theorem
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]